# What does the WebDAV index format look like?

Tags: webdav

What is the WebDAV format for displaying the directory index?
...I would like to display my own custom index through a WebDAV server.
Therefore I would like to know how I should create the index file so that it can be displayed unser a WebDAV server?
Thanks!
Frank

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a standard index format.

If you want a WebDAV *client* be able to access your server, you'll have to implement the protocol, as specified in RFC 4918.

Comment: there might be a misunderstanding. assuming I would like publish a standard windows folder using a WebDAV server installed. The server then must analyze the directory I would like to display in order to  publish the directory on the server, right? so there must be a format related to the operating system how the WebDAV server converts the local diretories to the format needed to publish it on the server.